# access a function or variable from a different script on an html page

Tags: javascript, html

Example,

I am trying to check if something is true on a specific section of the page or if there is a keyword anywhere on the page. I figured the best way to do this is with a js function that works but cant be accessed outside of the script. Here is an example

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    function evaluatesomething() {
            var brandUrl = document.getElementsByClassName("brand").item(1)["href"];

            console.log(Url);

            if (brandUrl.includes("something") == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }

</script>
```

How do I call it in another in another JS function like so:

```html
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div id="navbarInner" class="navbar-inner" >
                <div id="headercontainer" class="container">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      
                        if (evaluatesomething() == true) {
                        
                        }
                    </script>
```

Comment: first, why do you need so ? When you define your function, it is attached to the `window` object and so available everywhere (you still need to make sur the `<script>` element is fully loaded before to be able to call the  function inside it). A good practise is to define all you js scripts at the end of the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 0):

This call can be done when the entire script and html templates are loaded.
Eg:- You can call `function A()` from `function B()` if and only if `function A()` is loaded before `function B()`

```
<script>
    function A(){
        //some executable code here
    }
</script>
<div>
    <!-- some html templates -->
</div>
<script>
    function B(){
        //Call to function A()
        A();
    }
    //execute function B()
    B();
</script>
```

To simplify this, you could try jQuery's simple `$(document).ready` function which will execute the code only after the page is properly loaded (of course ignoring the images)

Comment: I tried your suggestion doing 

                      $(function() {

                          console.log('test!');

                      });  but nothing printed. Any suggestions why this would not execute?

Comment: I'm sorry but the only thing I can think of is that the jquery library is not loaded in the header.